# HTML table gets messy after I add more than a few headers

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to learn how to make a website using HTML on Notepad. I encountered this problem with tables.

For some reason, after I add more than one header, my table gets insanely screwed up. My table is shifted to the right:

[image]

```html
<h4>Header 4:Table</h4>
<table border="1">
    <th><h1>ItemX</h1></th>
    <th><h1>ItemX</h1></th>
    <th><h1>ItemX</h1></th>
    <tr style = "font-family:courier;background-color:orange;">
        <td><b>Item<b><td>
        <td><u>Item</u><td>
        <td><p style="background-color:grey;color:green;">Item</p><td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Item</a><td>
        <td>Item<td>
       <td><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/b7/ee/1e/b7ee1e0404e9ac12da5056a2d35df202.jpg" width = "50"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item<td>
        <td>Item<td>
        <td>Item<td>
        <td>Item<td>
        <td>Item<td>
        <td>Item<td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Share your code please comrade. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So you have a problem with your code, and yet you don't share it. What exactly are we supposed to to now?

Comment: Can You Post Your code here..

Comment: Why do you not wrapping your `th`s inside `tr`? And why do you show us an image instead of a real lines of code/markup?

Comment: Sorry about that... I'm new to stacksoverflow and didn't know you can't post more than 1 img as a new account

Comment: I was following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=if6DU2hYeWQ&list=PLOe0yeC6rxiiebh2m6ZRMDhS9oWrX1w0s&index=13&spfreload=5

Comment: SO provides you support for embed code in your post. You can use {} for format or you can add snippets too. Photos are not real the best way since it doesnt let copy paste and most of people is gonna prefer take your code as sample to explai you what you need.

Comment: Your have forgotten the slashes in the closing tags of the `<td>` cells: you have `<td>Item<td>` instead of `<td>Item</td>`. The poor browser cannot guess you mind, and when it sees `<td>` it blindly starts a new cell.

Comment: Thank you Alex :D Would upvote your comment but don't know how :P.

Comment: Don't know about that video, the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) say: _**Permitted parents** Any element that accepts flow content_

Comment: What does the page look like **before** you add multiple headers? A before & after comparison could help us debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution is this table example I have taken from the [W3C site](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) I recommend you to visit better than any youtube video for begining. I have stylized it to make the details remarkable.

```css
.black-table {
border: 2px solid grey;
font-family: 'Verdana';
color:white;
background:#070a07;
}

.black-table th {
border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.black-table td {
border-bottom: 1px dashed white;
}

.black-table td.age {
  text-align:center;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="black-table" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td class="age">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td class="age">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```